# customising Termdebug commands

Tags: terminal, debugging

There are commands such as `:Break` and `:Continue`, but I would like an `:Until` to run to the current line without setting a breakpoint.  Is it possible to add this myself, or would it need a vim feature request?

Answer (score 2):

It's documented at [:h termdebug_shortcuts](https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html#termdebug_shortcuts)

```
nnoremap ,u :call TermDebugSendCommand( printf( 'until %d', line('.') ) )<cr>
```

**update**

It's add at [patch 8.1.0071](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/b3307b5e7e) .

Tons of bugs have been fixed since 8.0, update to 8.1 or 8.2 if you can.

If you want to stay in 8.0, you can try to replace your termdebug.vim with [master version](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/pack/dist/opt/termdebug/plugin/termdebug.vim), it's located at `$VIMRUNTIME/pack/dist/opt/termdebug/plugin/termdebug.vim`, note that you should back up the original version, I'm not sure if it would work.

Comment: Thanks, that doesn't seem to be available in 8.0.  Do you know which version it was added?  Is anything else possible in 8.0?

Comment: @Rob See update